# SQL Server Join first two rows as two columns

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have two tables:

Table `User`:

```
Id, Name, Email,...
```

Table `Images`:

```
UserId, Priority, Path,...
```

I would like to create a view of users with two images of every user with highest priority resulting in something like this:

```
User.Id, User.Name, User.Email, Image1, Image2
-------------------------------------------------
```

I suppose, if there are no images for the user, both columns `Image1` and `Image2` will be `NULL`, if there is only one image, then `Image1` will be set and `Image2` will be `NULL`.

How can I achieve this most effectively? I mean database performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these sample schema / data used as a mock-up:

```
CREATE TABLE #User (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(MAX), Email VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #Images (UserId INT, [Priority] INT, [Path] VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #User VALUES
(1, 'Bob', 'bob@foo.com'),
(2, 'Jim', 'jim@foo.com')

INSERT INTO #Images VALUES
(1, 10, 'path1'),
(1, 5, 'path2'),
(1, 7, 'path3')
```

you can use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT UserId, [1] AS PathOfImage1, [2] AS PathOfImage2
FROM 
(SELECT UserId, [Path], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [Priority] DESC) AS rn
 FROM #Images ) AS source
 PIVOT 
 (
   MAX([Path])
   FOR rn IN ([1], [2])
 ) AS pvt
```

to get the *top* two images per user in a single record:

```
UserId  PathOfImage1    PathOfImage2
------------------------------------
1       path1           path3
```

Note that user with `Id=2` does not appear in the above result set, since he does not have any related images.

You can now perform and `OUTER APPLY` on the table expression produced by the above mentioned query:

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, Images.PathOfImage1, Images.PathOfImage2
FROM #User u
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT UserId, [1] AS PathOfImage1, [2] AS PathOfImage2
   FROM (
      SELECT UserId, [Path], 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [Priority] DESC) AS rn
      FROM #Images ) AS source
   PIVOT 
   (
      MAX([Path])
      FOR rn IN ([1], [2])
   ) AS pvt
   WHERE UserId = u.Id
) Images
```

in order to get the desired output:

```
Id  Name    PathOfImage1    PathOfImage2
----------------------------------------
1   Bob     path1           path3
2   Jim     NULL            NULL
```

**EDIT:**

If multiple columns should be pulled out of `Image` table, then `PIVOT` has to be replaced by old-style conditional aggregates, since SQL Server does not support multiple aggregates on `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT t.UserId, 
       [PathOfImage1] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Path] ELSE NULL END),
       [PathOfImage2] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Path] ELSE NULL END),
       [PriorityOfImage1] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Priority] ELSE NULL END),
       [PriorityOfImage2] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Priority] ELSE NULL END)
FROM (
  SELECT UserId, [Path], [Priority],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [Priority] DESC) AS rn
  FROM #Images ) t
GROUP BY t.UserId
```

Comment: Thanks, it works without the sharp. By the way why there is a sharp as a part of the table name. Is it something special?

Comment: @qub1n The `#` symbol is used to denote temp tables. I had to mock some sample data to test my query before posting it and temp tables are a quick way to do so.

Comment: @qub1n You can also try substituting `OUTER APPLY` with a `LEFT JOIN` and see how these two compare in terms of performance.

Comment: I am playing with this piece of code trying to add height and width of the image. Can you please give me a hint? I have put alle fields into MAX(ServerPath, Height, Width), but it seems to be wrong....

Comment: @qub1n Unfortunately SQL Server does not support multiple aggregates on `PIVOT`, thus you have to resort to traditional conditional aggregates. Have a look at the edit I made.